# Using modifier with Objection.js relationmapping

Tags: node.js, objection.js

I have four tables **vehicle_parts**, **part_pricing**, **labour_pricing** and **paint_pricing**. Vehicle_parts table is having one to many relationship with remaining tables. Each table is having a field `is_active` indicating whether record is active or not. So ideally for every part in vehicle_parts table there will be only one active price in part_pricing.

I am using Objection.js to build my model as shown below -
[image]

I have a function where i am querying the vehicle part model to fetch vehicle parts along with associated prices, as shown below -
[image]

I am using `withGraphFetched()` method to get relational data and i am getting that.

The problem i am facing is when i am getting vehicle parts, i am getting active parts only, however i am getting non-active prices as well along with active price in relational data.
I know this can be solved using modifiers but i am not sure how to use that. In simple words i need to check `is_Active` flag in every relation when fetching data using `withGraphFetched()`.

Thanks for sharing your wisdom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should apply filters in the model when setting up the relationship.

Like,
for example,

```js
part_pricing: {
    relation: BaseModel.HasManyRelation,
    modelClass: path.join(__dirname, '/PartPricing'),
    filter: (builder) => builder.where('is_active', true),
    join: {
        from: 'vehicle_parts.id',
        to: 'part_pricing.vehicle_part_id',
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the selected answer works, it limits all other subsequent queries for related items to active ones.
To solve this, one can add reusable modifier on each model class to filter using the `is active` flag.

```js
class VehiclePart extends Model{

  static get modifiers() {
    return {
      onlyActive(builder) {
        builder.where('vehicle_parts.is_active',true);
      },
     }
}
```

```js
class PartPricing extends Model{

  static get modifiers() {
    return {
      onlyActive(builder) {
        builder.where('part_pricing.is_active',true);
      },
     }
}
```

```js
class LaborPricing extends Model{

  static get modifiers() {
    return {
      onlyActive(builder) {
        builder.where('labour_pricing.is_active',true);
      },
     }
}
```

How to use the modifiers on the query

```js
VehiclePartModel.query()
 .select(vehiclePartsSelect)
.withGraphFetched('[part_pricing(onlyActive),labour_pricing(onlyActive)]')
.modify('onlyActive')
```

If you don't want to reuse the modifier, one can also register it on the query level using `modifiers` method of the query builder e.g.

```js
VehiclePartModel.query()
 .select(vehiclePartsSelect)
.withGraphFetched('[part_pricing(onlyActive),paint_pricing(activeFilter)]')
  .modifiers({
    activeFilter: query => query.where('paint_pricing.is_active',true)
  });
```

Reference docs

https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/model/static-properties.html#static-modifiers

https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/query-builder/other-methods.html#modifiers